# Delete/Reply/Spam buttons now hidden in the offline Gmail app?

Tags: email, gmail

I have used Gmail offline which show me delete and reply, spam option in right but it doesn't show for now.

Can someone check the image and let me know what happened. Is there any special trick to get them back?

[image: Hidden Buttons in Gmail]

Comment: What image? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @AlEverett Oops, I forget to post image link here.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is coming in too late but the following steps fixed my problem:

1. Disable Ad Block Plus on the offline gmail page
2. Reload the page

Thats all. You should get your menu back. Looks like ABP has been undergoing some updates that arent soo cool with the offline gmail recently
Hope that helps :)